# Bootstrap table responsive break word

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have table with more columns:

```css
.server-name {
  max-width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table serverlist">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="rank">Ранг</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="server-name">Имя</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="version">Версия</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="server-info">Сервер</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="status">Игроков</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="online">Статус</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="rating">Рейтинг</th>
      </tr></thead> 
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="rank">
          <span>1</span>
        </td> 
        <td class="server-name">
          <a href="">Luminex - Semi-RPG Survival</a></td> 
        <td class="version">
          <a href="">1.12.1</a>
        </td> 
        <td class="server-info">
          <div class="img-banner">
            <img src="http://minecraftrating.ru/uploads/servers/29700/29700.gif?8185" alt="">
          </div> 
          <div class="server-ip clearfix"><p><i class="ion-ios-world"></i> 
            <span>play.minesuperior.com</span></p> 
            <a href="#!" onclick="copyToClipboard('play.minesuperior.com', $(this))" class="copy-action"><span class="copy-text"><i class="ion-scissors"></i>
                          Копировать
                        </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </td> 
        <td class="status">18/27</td> 
        <td class="online"><span class="badge badge-success">Online</span></td>
        <td class="rating"><span class="balls">225 <i class="balls fa fa-star"></i></span> <span class="votes">335 <i class="votes fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></span></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need do break word on column server, where name = 40 symbols. Width and break-word not working and my column resize. Why? Width: 157px not working...

If do: display: block on server-name, then name up to column.

**UPDATE**

`Luminex - Semi-RPG Survival` not resize in all width..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need give width to the inner element of `td`.

```css
.server-name a {
  width: 157px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table serverlist">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="rank">Ранг</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="server-name">Имя</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="version">Версия</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="server-info">Сервер</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="status">Игроков</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="online">Статус</th> 
        <th scope="col" class="rating">Рейтинг</th>
      </tr></thead> 
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="rank">
          <span>1</span>
        </td> 
        <td class="server-name">
          <a href="">Luminex - Semi-RPG Survival</a></td> 
        <td class="version">
          <a href="">1.12.1</a>
        </td> 
        <td class="server-info">
          <div class="img-banner">
            <img src="http://minecraftrating.ru/uploads/servers/29700/29700.gif?8185" alt="">
          </div> 
          <div class="server-ip clearfix"><p><i class="ion-ios-world"></i> 
            <span>play.minesuperior.com</span></p> 
            <a href="#!" onclick="copyToClipboard('play.minesuperior.com', $(this))" class="copy-action"><span class="copy-text"><i class="ion-scissors"></i>
                          Копировать
                        </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </td> 
        <td class="status">18/27</td> 
        <td class="online"><span class="badge badge-success">Online</span></td>
        <td class="rating"><span class="balls">225 <i class="balls fa fa-star"></i></span> <span class="votes">335 <i class="votes fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></span></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please see my updated question.. string: `Luminex - Semi-RPG Survival` not in all width resize.. Why?